# Pandas Scatter Plots with X labels and aesthetically pleasing formats

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib

I'm creating scatter plots for a bunch of different properties in my data set:

```
import numpy as np
for i, group in df.groupby('property_name'):
    plt.figure()
    group.plot(kind='scatter',x='Week', y='true_duration', title=str(i), grid=True)
    plt.xticks(np.arange(min(df['Week']),max(df['Week']), 2))
    plt.show()
```

This works in creating the scatter plot for each property; however they aren't good scatter plots  as seen in this image:

[image: scatterplot]

I want to fix it so it doesn't overlap on the x axis, I also would like it to not have those weird white spaces on either side.

Lastly, is their a way to add a table below each plot with some descriptive statistics on the data in that chart? Really just looking for mean, median, max, and min.

Thanks for any help!

my panda df looks like this:

```
property_name    Week     true_duration
A                 1           3
A                 3           5
B                 1           2.4
C                 3           5
C                 4           6
C                 5           4
D                 2           1
```

Comment: Can you please provide code to recreate `df`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

***setup***
This is my simulation of what you have

```
np.random.seed([3,1415])
df = pd.DataFrame(dict(Week=np.random.randint(33, 53, 20),
                       true_duration=np.random.randint(9, 18, 20)))
df.iloc[-1, :] = pd.Series(dict(Week=1, true_duration=7))

df.plot(kind='scatter',x='Week', y='true_duration', grid=True)
plt.xticks(np.arange(min(df['Week']),max(df['Week']), 2));
```

[image]

---

***option 1***
Skip the `plt.ticks`

```
df.plot(kind='scatter',x='Week', y='true_duration', grid=True)
```

[image]

***option 2***
widen out the ticks

```
df.plot(kind='scatter',x='Week', y='true_duration', grid=True)
plt.xticks(np.arange(min(df['Week']) - 5,max(df['Week']) + 5, 5));
```

[image]

***option 3***
rotate the ticks

```
df.plot(kind='scatter',x='Week', y='true_duration', grid=True, rot=90)
plt.xticks(np.arange(min(df['Week']),max(df['Week']), 2));
```

[image]

***option 4***
any combination of the above

```
df.plot(kind='scatter',x='Week', y='true_duration', grid=True, rot=90)
plt.xticks(np.arange(min(df['Week']) - 5,max(df['Week']) + 5, 5));
```

[image]

Comment: I've rotated and that's helpful, yet I still get that awkward space on the sides of my chart that are empty. Do you know how to change that by chance? Also, any idea how to add some summary statistics to the bottom of each chart? Appreciate the help (I added more code on my df in my question). @piRSquared

Comment: @JoshDautel Summary Stats is another question.  Notice in option 2, I added 5 to the max and subtracted 5 from the left?

Comment: ok I'll try that. and yeah, I didn't know if there was a way to append summary stats to the bottom of each table with matplotlib.